# GZIP Compression achieved in C# MVC fails when being read by a client application which is in Java

Tags: java, c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am compressing a XML byte stream to GZIP. To achieve this I am retrieving the XML data from a procedure in the DB, the XML is fine. The issue rises during compression and transmission.

The steps involved as follows

1. Compress the XML stream
2. Encode the XML stream to base64 with an utility provided by the client.
3. Sign the string generated in step 2 using a Digital Certificate
4. Transmit the entire data as JSON encrypted object using an utility provided by client.

Steps 2-4 are extensively used in my application and I am certain that there are no errors in those stages. I have realised after the provision of the logs by the client that the compression step, i.e. step 1 is creating an issue.

The code for compression is as follows

```
public static byte[] Compress(byte[] data)
{
    using(var compressedStream=new MemoryStream())
    using(var zipStream=new GZipStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Compress)
    {
        zipStream.Write(data,0,data.Length);
        zipStream.Close();
        return compressedStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Below is the log from the client

2017 15:19:11,299 | httpInt_fuse: | ERROR | d #321 - Threads | GzipUtil                         | 355 - PaymentReconService - 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT | Exception caught:Not in GZIP format|[java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readHeader(GZIPInputStream.java:165), java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.(GZIPInputStream.java:79), java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.(GZIPInputStream.java:91), org.gst.camel.util.GzipUtil.decompress(GzipUtil.java:24), org.gst.camel.processor.LuggageProcessor.process(LuggageProcessor.java:100), org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateSyncProcessor.process(DelegateSyncProcessor.java:63), org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77), org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:468), org.apache.camel.pr...

2017 15:19:11,299 | httpInt_fuse: | INFO  | d #321 - Threads | GzipUtil                         | 355 - PaymentReconService - 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT | Exiting process() at 1508147351299

2017 15:19:11,299 | httpInt_fuse: | ERROR | d #321 - Threads | LuggageProcessor                 | 355 - PaymentReconService - 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT | PaymentReconService|process|Failure|reqid:2578|bankUrl:http://202.138.100.107/GSTNReconciliation/GetLuggageFileDetails|fileNo:1|IOException caught:Not in GZIP format|[java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readHeader(GZIPInputStream.java:165), java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.(GZIPInputStream.java:79), java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.(GZIPInputStream.java:91), org.gst.camel.util.GzipUtil.decompress(GzipUtil.java:24), org.gst.camel.processor.LuggageProcessor.process(LuggageProcessor.java:100), org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateSyncProcessor.process(DelegateSyncProcessor.java:63), org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77), org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHand...

2017 15:19:11,299 | httpInt_fuse: | ERROR | d #321 - Threads | LuggageProcessor                 | 355 - PaymentReconService - 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT | |errorFlag:true|reqid:2578|

Additional Note:

1. I have decrypted the data and tried to Decompress using my MVC Application, the stream gets decompressed and the input XML is obtained as an output.

Comment: When you write the bytes created after compression in C# to a file, can you decompress it with the `gunzip` command line utility or the corresponding part of your Java application?

Comment: Are you really sure that the decryption part of your Java application is working without errors?

Comment: reply for comment 1: I have developed the code in C# and the de-compression works for the said stream. I de-compressed the byte stream in my c# code itself.

Comment: reply for comment 2: Yes, the decryption occurs in not my application but in the application of the client which is hosted in their environment, but they use a common utility for encryption and decryption which is provided to us. I have tried the decryption using the utility and it works at my end. Also we send a lot of encrypted requests using the same utility and all the aspects work perfectly.

Comment: Hm, then you need to reproduce the error. And you need the abylity to change the Java application or the cooperation of the Java application's developers. On your side you calculate a hash value for the content after each processing step (like CRC32 or MD5). So you have the hash value after compression, the hash value after encryption and the hash value after Base64 conversion. All these hash values should be locked. Then in the Java application the same hash values have to be calculated and logged.